# predict function in BMA package produces 'subscript out of bounds'

Tags: r, model, bayesian, predict

I'm trying to use `R`'s `BMA` package to make some fitted predictions but no matter what I do it either tells me "subscript our of bounds" or "newdata is missing variables". I have the following example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(x=runif(50),
                    y=runif(50),
                    z=runif(50),
                    u=runif(50),
                    v=runif(50),
                    w=runif(50),
                    s=runif(50),
                    t=runif(50),
                    r=runif(50))

x <- data1[,-1]
y <- data1[,1]

BMAex <- bicreg(x, y)
summary(BMAex)

result <- predict(BMAex, x)
```

until `summary`everything works fine and the corresponding models are displayed. But the `predict` itself fails. I have also tried removing the dropped variables from `x` but it still won't work. Can you help me see what I'm missing? Thanks in advance!